# How do you add validation to a Reads in Play Json?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Let's say I've got a reads that creates an object from JSON with two optional fields:

```
implicit val rd: Reads[MyObject] = (
  (__ \ "field1").readNullable[String] and
  (__ \ "field2").readNullable[String]
)(MyObject.apply _)
```

I want to check to make sure that the value of field1 is one of the values in the list:

```
  List("foo", "bar")
```

I can do that after the fact, by creating a new MyObject and mapping the values through a function to transform them, but I feel like there should be a way to do this more elegantly using JSON transformers or something.

Ideally, I want the Reads to read the nullable value of field1 and transform it if it is defined, without the need to post-process it.  Is there some way of sneaking a transform in there?

Comment: field1 should be only: Some("foo"), Some("bar") or None, right?

Comment: That's right.  Which means that the JSON could be missing field1 altogether, which may complicate things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
case class MyObject(a: Option[String], b: Option[String])

val allowedValues = Seq("foo", "bar")

implicit val reads: Reads[MyObject] = new Reads[MyObject] { 
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[MyObject] = { 
    val a = (json \ "a").asOpt[String].filter(allowedValues.contains)
    val b = (json \ "b").asOpt[String]
    JsSuccess(MyObject(a, b))
  }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
scala> Json.parse(""" { "a": "bar", "b": "whatever"} """).validate[MyObject]
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[MyObject] = JsSuccess(MyObject(Some(bar),Some(whatever)),)

scala> Json.parse(""" { "a": "other", "b": "whatever"} """).validate[MyObject]
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[MyObject] = JsSuccess(MyObject(None,Some(whatever)),)

scala> Json.parse(""" {} """).validate[MyObject]
res4: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[MyObject] = JsSuccess(MyObject(None,None),)
```

Comment: That works all right.  I still feel like there should be (or maybe ought to be) a way to plug a transformer into that in a more modular way, but this is fine for now.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after doing some more research, I came up with the following:

In `play.api.libs.json.ConstraintReads` there is a function called `verifying(cond: A => Boolean)` that returns a `Reads[A]`.  This can be passed as a parameter to `JsPath.readNullable[A]` like so:

```
implicit val rd: Reads[MyObject] = (
  (__ \ "field1").readNullable[String](verifying(allowedValues.contains)) and
  (__ \ "field2").readNullable[String]
)(MyObject.apply _)
```

This will return a JsResponse, either a JsSuccess if "field1" validates, or a JsError if it doesn't validate.  It actually fails on an invalid input, rather than just ignoring the input.  That's more like the behaviour I wanted.

There are a number of other constraint functions that perform similar tests on the read value, as well.